# Click Once deployment of a winForm application

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, publish

I have a winform applications which is a legacy application in my organization and I had to make some enhancements. The application runs fine on my local, however I am not able to publish it. In the final stage of publishing I get a prompt "Enter password to open File SOMv1.1.1._TemporaryKey.pfx".

I also see the above file as a part of the solution folder.

My question is what is this .pfx file? How to either retrieve the password it requires to finish publishing Or How to reset the password?

Thanks

Comment: I think the pfx file is a Certificate. If you see on Windows 7 when you run programs that require Administrator privileges, then a dialog is shown, if the Publisher is Unknown then the dialog box is Yellow and White, otherwise the dialog is Aqua/Blue and White, which means that it is from a trusted source, hence the certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have access to the source of this project you can simply remove the .pfx file and then add a new one.

Given that you are creating a new version of the application it won't matter that the .pfx file has changed.

For reference the .pfx file is a "Personal Information Exchange file" which stores the public/private key pair for the security certificate.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: When I do that I get another error "Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store."

Comment: To fix the above error I simply chose the newly created .pfx file for Click Once Manifest.